# .Net Maui LongPress

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I have a page that contains a CollectionView of images.  I want the user to be able to LongPress on an image and then they will have the option to delete or edit the image.

I'm trying to implement LongPress functionality in my .Net Maui project, however I can't find any documentation for this.  How do you guys handle LongPress?  Am I missing something?

Comment: A quick google search shows me this : https://dev.to/dotnet/collectionview-selectionmode-with-navigation-and-longpress-33f

Comment: @FreakyAli Yes, I saw that too.  It's using TouchEffects from the Xamarin Community Toolkit.  Is that okay to use in a .Net Maui project? I never developed a Xamarin project.

Comment: For now yes but make sure that when the update for it comes to Maui Toolkit and its clear of the bugs you migrate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the [TouchEffect has not yet been ported](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/issues/86) from Xamarin Community Toolkit to Maui Community Toolkit, you can add the [Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.MauiCompat 2.0.2-preview1013](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.MauiCompat/) to your project. It is the .NET MAUI Compatible version of Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.

Here is the codes you can directly run in the package manager console to add this package:

```
NuGet\Install-Package Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.MauiCompat -Version 2.0.2-preview1013
```

Comment: And then what?  This doesn't say how to actually make long press work.

Comment: This won't work with .NET 7 + 8. This only works with the very old / deprecated .NET 6

Answer (score 0):

The Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.MauiCompat doesn't work with .NET 7 and .NET 8.

For now, at the time i'm writing this post, you can use this repo: https://github.com/felipebaltazar/TouchEffect.Maui